# Help evaluating this endless double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

i tried to solve this integral many times and failed. Can someone help me solve it?

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{y=0}^{y=a} \int_{x= \frac{y^{2}}{a}}^{x=y} \frac{x}{(a-x) \sqrt{ax-y^{2}}}\,dx\,dy$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the order of integration

$$\int_0^a \frac{x}{a-x}dx \int_x^{\sqrt{ax}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax-y^2}}dy = \int_0^a \frac{x}{a-x} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\right)\right) dx$$

Now since $\frac{\pi}{2} -\arcsin z = \arccos z$, substitute  $x = a\cos^2\theta$

$$=2a\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\theta \cot\theta\cos^2\theta d\theta$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much